# How to display median with compareGroups package?

Tags: r, median

I have this code:

```
data("ToothGrowth")
res<-compareGroups(supp~len, data = ToothGrowth)
restab<-createTable(res, show.p.overall = FALSE, extra.labels=c("","",""))
print(restab, which.table = "descr")
```

It gives me this output (with mean and standard deviation):

```
--------Summary descriptives table by 'supp'---------

______________________________________ 
                   OJ          VC      
                  N=30        N=30     
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯ 
len, Mean (SD) 20.7 (6.61) 17.0 (8.27) 
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
```

**Question:** How to make it also output median? I need by group summary in html format of mean median and standard deviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you consider a solution with dplyr rather than compareGroups? You can add any statistic you want.

```
library(dplyr)

data("ToothGrowth")

df<-ToothGrowth %>%
  group_by(supp) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(len), 
            median = median(len),
            sd = sd(len),
            count = n())

df

# # A tibble: 2 x 5
# supp   mean median    sd count
# <fct> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1 OJ     20.7   22.7  6.61    30
# 2 VC     17.0   16.5  8.27    30
```

You can format the result (or any dataframe) as an HTML table with the package knitr. You'll find formatting options in the `kable` help file; the add-on package kableExtra lets you do a lot more.

```
knitr::kable(df, format = "html", digits = 2)

# <table>
#   <thead>
#   <tr>
#   <th style="text-align:left;"> supp </th>
#   <th style="text-align:right;"> mean </th>
#   <th style="text-align:right;"> median </th>
#   <th style="text-align:right;"> sd </th>
#   <th style="text-align:right;"> count </th>
#   </tr>
#   </thead>
#   <tbody>
#   <tr>
#   <td style="text-align:left;"> OJ </td>
#   <td style="text-align:right;"> 20.66333 </td>
#   <td style="text-align:right;"> 22.7 </td>
#   <td style="text-align:right;"> 6.605561 </td>
#   <td style="text-align:right;"> 30 </td>
#   </tr>
#   <tr>
#   <td style="text-align:left;"> VC </td>
#   <td style="text-align:right;"> 16.96333 </td>
#   <td style="text-align:right;"> 16.5 </td>
#   <td style="text-align:right;"> 8.266029 </td>
#   <td style="text-align:right;"> 30 </td>
#   </tr>
#   </tbody>
#   </table>
#   > kable(df, format = "html", digits = 2)
# <table>
#   <thead>
#   <tr>
#   <th style="text-align:left;"> supp </th>
#   <th style="text-align:right;"> mean </th>
#   <th style="text-align:right;"> median </th>
#   <th style="text-align:right;"> sd </th>
#   <th style="text-align:right;"> count </th>
#   </tr>
#   </thead>
#   <tbody>
#   <tr>
#   <td style="text-align:left;"> OJ </td>
#   <td style="text-align:right;"> 20.66 </td>
#   <td style="text-align:right;"> 22.7 </td>
#   <td style="text-align:right;"> 6.61 </td>
#   <td style="text-align:right;"> 30 </td>
#   </tr>
#   <tr>
#   <td style="text-align:left;"> VC </td>
#   <td style="text-align:right;"> 16.96 </td>
#   <td style="text-align:right;"> 16.5 </td>
#   <td style="text-align:right;"> 8.27 </td>
#   <td style="text-align:right;"> 30 </td>
#   </tr>
#   </tbody>
#   </table>
```

Comment: It is nice example, but I need to export this as html so I can include it in Word file as table (that is why I am using compareGroups). Is it possible to add code for html table generation (with or without additional packages)?

Comment: @vasili111 I've added code to my answer to format the table in HTML. If this works for you, then could you edit your question to to reflect what your trying to achieve -- a by-group summary in an html table?